# Kafka Stream - Aggregating data from multiple instances local KTables

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have multiple instance of `MyApp` listening to different partition with local state store KTables. I know we can use RPC to query remote cache store [Reference](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html#querying-remote-state-stores-for-the-entire-app).

But problem is I don't want to use REST Endpoints, what I want is to have a SSE (Server-Sent Event) layer on top of `MyApp` which should listen to the change in local state store KTables and publish events. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: You can write all updates into a topic via `KTable#toStrream()#to` and consumer from the topic. If you want to do it in the same app, maybe `KTable#toStream()#foreach()` helps. Note, that you might want to disable caching on the `KTable` if you want to get *every* update.

Comment: Since I don't want duplicate updates for same key, caching would be better solution for me? When you say writing to another topic do you mean I will have to do it in all `MyApp` instances?

Comment: Yes, you app `MyApp` is just publishing the updates to a topic and other applications that are interested just consumer the topic. -- Not sure what you exactly mean by "duplicate updates" -- real duplicates are hard to detect and I guess you just need to accept them. If you however refer to high frequent updates and want to reduce load, caching may help -- for more fine grained configurations consider using `suppress()`.

Comment: You could also use Interactive Queries to let other application query the stores, but that would be a "pull" patterns, while "publishing" implies a "push" pattern.